# Can I add aggregated column without performing a join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table `table1` with three columns `a, b, c`. I am creating another column by doing a group by on `c` and some function `func(a,b) as d` giving me `view1`. In order to add the column `d` to `table1`, the only thing I can think of is to perform a join between `view1` and `table1`. However, both of them have millions of rows and it gets really slow. Is there any other way without joining them? It looks intuitively that it should be possible.

Here is a snippet of the script

```
with 

found_mean
as
(select sum(count*avg)/sum(count) as combined_avg , b from view_1 group by b),

view_1_m
as
(select combined_avg , count , avg, variance , found_mean.b from found_mean , view_1 where       found_mean.b = view_1.b),
```

Comment: can you post your SQL here? if you're aggregating data from a single table you won't have to join anything - you can perform aggregates and pump their values into another table without it

Comment: Look up "window functions"; they're like aggregate functions calculated alongside the main results. The exact syntax can be a little confusing though, as they have lots of options for what exactly to aggregate.

Comment: @nbpeth I have added the relevant part of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your function is, you can use window functions (sometimes called analytic functions).  For instance, if you wanted the maximum value of `b` for a given `a`:

```
select a, b, c, max(b) over (partition by a) as d
from table1;
```

Without more information, it is hard to be more specific.

EDIT:

You should be able to do this with analytic functions:

```
select count , avg, variance,
       (sum(count * avg) over (partition by b) /
        sum(count) over (partition by b)
       ) as weighted_average
from view_1;
```

Comment: combined_avg is not a column in `table1`. After removing it and running the query, I get an error that `view_1.count` must appear in the group by clause. I think that `partition by` should work though. I am trying to figure it out now and will update with the correct answer if you cannot update yours.

Comment: @user1150989 . . . My bad.  Added in the missing partitioning clause.

Comment: To clarify the terminology, these "analytic functions" are called "window functions" in the Postgres manual.

Comment: @IMSoP . . . Thank you for the clarification.  I mistakenly thought that Postgres used the Oracle terminology for these functions, but the documentation is exceedingly clear:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html.